# Pass JSON var from route to ejs

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have some codes in express+EJS,

1) in app.js , the mongo collection object is created,

```
app.locals.userCollection = db.get('userData');
```

2) in user.js express route file, I get the data from this DB connection and want to pass it to EJS to render,

```
exports.list = function(req, res){
   req.app.locals.userCollection.find({},function(err , returnValue){
       if(returnValue.length>0){          
          res.render('user', res.locals.returnValue);
       }
       return err;
       });
```

};

3) In user.ejs I try access it using

```
<div><script>
var test = <%- returnValue %>;
```

It gives me returnValue is not defined error.

May I know if i want to access returnValue[0].attr1, what I should code in route and EJS?

Regards
Hammer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try following:

In Node.js:

`res.render('user', data: res.locals.returnValue);`

In EJS:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var rows =<%-JSON.stringify(data)%>
  alert(rows);
</script>
```

---

**Update** (as per questions asked in comments)**:**

If you want to loop over the `rows` then you should not use `JSON.stringify()` since it converts your object into `String` and you may try doing the following (following code works if the data put by server is array object).

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    <% data.forEach(function(dataRow, idxOfRow, orgnlAryObject) {
        // You can directly use the dataRow to get each row from the array Object `data`
        //alert(JSON.stringify(dataRow)); // <== You can try this
    }); %>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Amol. Though I think there is still a monior modification that ,res.render('user', data: res.locals.returnValue); should be res.render('user', {data: returnValue});

Comment: @Hammer should be? Its is already.. `res.render('user', {data: returnValue});`

Comment: Amol, is there a way I can iterate through data? like <script>
    var rows =<%-JSON.stringify(data)%>
</script>
<% for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {%>
   <li><%= rows[i] %></li>
<% } %>

Comment: @Hammer: If you want to loop on the `rows` then it should be instance of Array. In your case, if you want to loop over. Then try to use `Array.isArray(rows);` if it returns true then loop over (don't stringify it). I will update sample code as well in Updated section of my answer.

Comment: @AmolMKulkarni what if my JSON data is large. when i do, <%-json.stringify(data) %> , it takes a long time and blocks eventloop.

Comment: @vardha: EJS is a template engine & when you use `<%-  %>` it gives you the raw output, So now you know where the `json.stringify()` operation executes on **server** or on **client**. I am sure you will understand the related answer on your question's http://stackoverflow.com/a/33884595/1933917

Comment: @AmolMKulkarni 0 thanks for the reply . i do know that this is executed on the server side. but i was wondering if there was a solution to processing very long nested json objects. I download the JSON from a server, process it and pass it to ejs and get the value of json using <%- JSON.stringify(data) %> but if the JSON is long , it takes very long time .. I ll be glad to take a look at the article you linked me to . thanks

Comment: @vardha: 1st thing the article link is the answer to the question you asked earlier, you can that accept the answer. and 2nd point "*very long nested json; it takes very long time*" Need to see details to answer, it could be because of multiple reasons like network latency,etc.. You can ask a new question with all the necessary information - everyone will try to give you a good answer :) Happy coding