# EJS access express variable in JS onload function

Tags: javascript, node.js, onload, ejs

I know you can get the value of variables in an ejs file like so,

```
<h1><%= title %></h1>
```

if i were to use the same title variable in a onload javascript function in the same ejs page, how would i use it . for instance

```
<script>
window.onload(){
var s = <%= title %>
alert(s);
}
</script>
```

this function produces a console error saying

> Uncaught syntax error: Unexpected identifier

although I'm able to see the actual value of the variable

Answer (score 4):

To output it within a script, the result will need to be understood as code.

Since you didn't note the value of `title`, I'll assume for the examples:

```
res.render('view', { title: 'My Site' });
```

---

When you use `var s = <%= title %>`, this results in creating the statement as:

```
var s = My Site
```

In this, `My` and `Site` are interpreted as individual variables separated only by an unexpected space. The engine is confused when it reaches `Site` without an operator between them, thus the `Unexpected identifier` you're getting.

---

It needs to instead create the statement:

```
var s = "My Site"
```

So the client script can also understand it as a string value.

One trick to accomplishing this is using [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). Since JSON took its syntax from JavaScript's expressions and literals, a JavaScript engine is capable of making sense of the result in many contexts (though, with its own take on strings, objects, etc.):

```
var s = <%- JSON.stringify(title) %>
```

Note, though, the switch to using `<%- %>` vs. `<%= %>`. This will disable HTML encoding, which is unnecessary and can lead to odd results inside of a `<script>`.

Comment: @vardha: This should be the accepted answer. Nicely explained and to the point.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try:
html:

```
<h1 id="title"><%= title %></h1>
```

Js:

```
  <script>
    window.onload(){
    var s = document.getElementById("title").innerText;
    alert(s);
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: I added ";" in line number three

Comment: This is what i tried but was wondering if this is the right approach(assign it to a html tag (style=hidden) and then getting the value during onload

Answer (score 0):

When you have

```js
var s = <%= title %>
```

This parses it like it would for HTML, so there are no quotes. For example, if the title was "My Page", your javascript would be:

```
var s = My Page
```

Since there are no quotes around My Page, this gives a JavaScript error. You could use `JSON.parse`, or just put quotes around it to fix this:

```
var s = "<%= title %>"
```