# How to make dynamic cards with array/string html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I have a data

```
    {
        "data": {
            "count": 8,
            "rows": [
                {
                    "session_name": "1_M1",
                    "date": "09-09-2021",
                    "p_id": "WEB506",
                    "sub_id": "Physiotherapy"
                },
                {
                    "session_name": "WEB506_09092021_M1",
                    "date": "09-09-2021",
                    "p_id": "WEB506",
                    "sub_id": "Physiotherapy"
                },
                {
                    "session_name": "WEB506_09092021_M1",
                    "date": "09-09-2021",
                    "p_id": "WEB506",
                    "sub_id": "Physiotherapy"
                },
                {
                    "session_name": "WEB506_09092021_M1",
                    "date": "09-09-2021",
                    "p_id": "WEB506",
                    "sub_id": "Physiotherapy"
                },
                {
                    "session_name": "WEB506_09092021_M1",
                    "date": "09-09-2021",
                    "p_id": "WEB506",
                    "sub_id": "Physiotherapy"
                },
                {
                    "session_name": "WEB506_09092021_M1",
                    "date": "09-09-2021",
                    "p_id": "WEB506",
                    "sub_id": "Physiotherapy"
                },
                {
                    "session_name": "WEB506_09092021_M1",
                    "date": "09-09-2021",
                    "p_id": "WEB506",
                    "sub_id": "Physiotherapy"
                },
                {
                    "session_name": "WEB506_09092021_M1",
                    "date": "09-09-2021",
                    "p_id": "WEB506",
                    "sub_id": "Physiotherapy"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

which I get from a post API(nodejs, express) by handling an ajax. I'm saving this data in localstorage and accessing it by localstorage on the next page. Then I want to create dynamic cards with passing some values from this data. the problem is I'm getting this data inside my script on the next page but foreach is not working when I create cards. please help.

my ajax,

```
    $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                 contentType: 'application/json',
                 dataType: 'json',
                 url: "http://localhost:5000/SessionData",                      
                 success: function(data) {
                
                     console.log(data);
    
                    
                     localStorage.setItem('myData', JSON.stringify(data));
                     window.location.href = 'nextpage'
                    },
                    
                  error: function(){
                    alert("Error")
                    console.log('error occured')
                  }
            })
```

and in my next page,

```
     <script>
        var data = localStorage.getItem('myData');
        console.log(data);
        var arr = new Array(data);
        console.log(arr,"arr");
        const container = document.getElementById('aa');
    
    arr.data.forEach((result, idx) => {
      // Create card element
      const card = document.createElement('div');
      card.classList = 'card-body';
    
      // Construct card content
      const content = `
        <div class="card" style="width:700px;height: 150px">
      
         
        
    
        
          <div class="card-body">
    
            <li> Session Name :${result.sub_id}</li>
            <li> Date :${result.date}</li>
            <li> Patient ID : ${result.p_id}</li>
            <button class="btn btn-link" style="width: 60px;height: 30px;background-color:#d1b147;color data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-${idx}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-${idx}">
              View
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      `;
    
      
      container.innerHTML += content;
    })
        
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the stored `string` back to an `object`,e.g. using [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
const parsedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myData'));
parsedData.data.rows.forEach((result, idx) => {
   ...
});
```

Comment: worked perfectly. thank you so much. can i ask you one more thing.

Comment: Sure, although a question should focus on one specific question :) Also don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left!

Comment: yeah bro, one question.  can i inject this myData to ejs tags inside this page itself? instead of making html  inside script

Comment: You mean like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/22907351/3761628

Comment: yes , somewhat it is what i want but using the data from ajax success is bit confusing. What i'm trying to convey is i'm getting the data from an ajax call . then i need to iterate the array to ejs tags. apologies if i'm confusing yoiu

Comment: Hmm, I think if you're getting the data through ajax from an external service, I think you can't. If the data is coming from your own service, you can just pass it through `res.render(..)` as described in the link above.

Comment: hi i have raised a question regarding this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69463471/how-to-pass-data-to-ejs-tags-from-an-ajax-success